# Terminology: groups whose elements are their own actions

Tags: group-theory, terminology, group-actions, semigroups, monoid

Consider groups (or more generally monoids or semigroups) whose elements are functions and whose action $T$ is defined by the formula $T(s,x)=s(x)$.

Is there a name for such groups "whose elements are their own actions"?

Comment: In the setting of representation theory of groups, this is usually called the "regular representation", I do not know wether it is called the "Regular action" when restricted to the setting of group actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the case of a group action, let me suppose that the mathematical object on which the group is acting has been specified, i.e. the set of all elements $X = \{x\}$ equipped with whatever mathematical structure is appropriate, for example: a topology; or a vector space structure; or whatever. In that case I would refer to this kind of group action as a **subgroup of $\textbf{Aut}(X)$**, where $\text{Aut}(X)$ is the group of automorphisms of $X$, i.e. self-isomorphisms.

For the case of a monoid action, one uses $\text{End}(X)$ for the monoid of self-endomorphisms of $X$, and then your action could be called a **submonoid of $\textbf{End}(X)$**.

I'll say that the full information being used here to define $\text{Aut}(x)$ and $\text{End}(X)$ is a category of which $X$ is an object, for example: the category of topological spaces and continuous maps; or the category of vector spaces and linear maps over some field; or whatever.

Comment: So "subsemigroup of the semigroup of all endomorphisms of some set". Too verbose. It's sad, if there is no short term for this. I may need to invent one. Could you suggest a short phrase or word to use?

Comment: Invented: "functional semigroup action".

Comment: I'll add that definitional terminology is driven by demand and application, so I don't have anything in particular to say, not knowing what this might be needed before.

Answer (score 3):

Any group can be viewed in this way: identify an element $g$ with its corresponding left action $g(x)=g \cdot x$.

Comment: But not the reverse: If the set of elements on which the actions are taken is not the same as the set of the elements of the group, then it cannot "be viewed in this way". So this is not an answer (don't delete it however, your answer is useful).